# Is it safe using 2 context managers in the same with clause to modify a file in-place?

Tags: python, contextmanager

Let's consider a `foo` function transforming a string, for the sake of completeness example below:

```
def foo(data):
    ### processes data in a fancy way ###
    return data.lower() # :P
```

I was wondering if it'd be a good idea replacing the typical pattern which modifies a file in-place like this:

```
# snippet1
with open(path, "r") as f:
    out = foo(f.read())

with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.write(out)
```

By this other one:

```
# snippet2
with open(path, "r") as f1:
    out = foo(f1.read())
    with open(path, "w") as f2:
        f2.write(out)
```

Is this safe to do in all possible scenarios?

Relevant info https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: I don't think context managers are relevant in this scenario. The problem is with having two handles to a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with context managers. Two context managers work fine! The problem is here:

```
open("path", "w")
```

When you open for writing, the file is truncated. In other words, all the data is deleted. Reading afterwards will show that the file is empty.

So you have to do this in two steps.

Comment: I've edited my question, sorry by the previous one, that case was just stupid and irrelevant, my bad :P

Comment: @BPL: After the edit, I'm not sure it will work on Windows. I don't have a Windows system at hand to test, though.